# In the school hall .

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

> In the school hall, 7/31 of the chairs are arranged in rows of 5 and 11/31 of the chairs are arranged in rows of 13. The rest of the chairs are stacked up. If there are less than 4000 chairs in the hall, find the total number of chairs in the hall.

Comment: What do you mean by "rows 5" and "rows 13"? If you mean 5 rows resp. 13 rows as in "in every row there is the same number of chairs", then you can use the assumption that the number of chairs is an integer to solve the problem; e.g. the total number should better be divisible by 31. :)

Comment: I edited . I just write it again from my book .

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so let's assume that in the 5 resp. 13 rows, the number of chairs is the same in every row. Let X be the total number of chairs, Y the number of chairs for the five rows and Z the number for the 13 rows. Then X is divisible by 31, as otherwise 7/31 and 11/31 would not be integers.
In the same way, Y is divisible by 5 and Z by 13, I'll leave the argumentation to you here.
As Y and Z are related to X, this gives new information on divisors for X.

Make your list of numbers that have to divide X so big that only one number smaller than 4000 fits (hint: least common multiply).